# Foreach array and create new array based on index then loop through that

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is probably really simple, but it's kicking my butt..

I have a json array containing around 5,000 video items by  id, category, title, score, review.   arranged by descending id.

I'm foreach-ing through the array, to create new arrays based on the category (there are 10 categories) to later loop through.

```
 foreach ($array as $item) {  // the original array
 $cid=$item['category'];
 $chanmov[$cid]['id'][]=$item['id'];
 $chanmov[$cid]['title'][]=$item['title'];
 $chanmov[$cid]['score'][]=$item['score'];
 $chanmov[$cid]['review'][]=$item['review'];
 }
```

Later I want to loop through the category ids, and pull out the list of that categorys videos   video id, title, score,review.

If I print_r  by a category id manually - e.g. print_r($chanmov['9'])  I get an array of data exactly as expected.

However, where I'm falling over is how to later loop back through the values and pull out the info

e.g. 
    CATEGORY ACTION

```
id        title            score    review
1753 - Demolition Man [1993] -  5    -  not bad
2123 - Death Wish [1974]     - 10    -  Awesome
3748 - Point Break [1991]   - 6      -  pretty good
```

I've tried  (  '$chid' is each category id  )

```
foreach($chanmov['$chid'] as $movie) {
echo $movie['id']." - ".$movie['title']."<br/>";
}
```

That gives an "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" error.

I've tried so many combinations that my head is spinning, I also tried while loops (after changing the first loop to add a counter) but nothing is working.

I know this should not be this hard...

BTW, I HATE arrays..

Any help sincerely appreciated

Comment: You aren't creating an array for each category. You are creating 4 arrays for each category. So, I think you want to change how you create the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you really want to make your structure like this:

```
foreach ($array as $item) {  // the original array
    $cid=$item['category'];
    $chanmov[$cid][]=$item;
}
```

And then your final loop for a given `$chid` would be:

```
foreach($chanmov[$chid] as $movie) {
    echo $movie['id']." - ".$movie['title']."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Oh boy.. Of course.  That works great.  Thank you.  Sorry, I can't upvote you because not enough points.